# What is the functionality of "sync contacts" in Exchange account in Email application?

Tags: android

Hi i am testing android E-mail application . I have configured an Exchange account where in i could find an option "Sync Contacts from this account" in Account settings.

According to my understanding if i check "sync contacts from the account" option , i must be able to access contacts in the exchange account i have configured. But i don't know how to get/access these contacts in android email application.

Can any one who have used this functionality or know about it can suggest to me how to make use of "Sync contacts" functionality. Or if you have any idea about, how i can test this functionality, i am very eager to here to you.

Kinds & Regards
Santhosh Kumar H.E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will sync GAL(Global address list) of the exchange account to local Contacts application on the phone . This helps saving contacts from GAL to local contacts directly and many more things.